# I cannot get opto-coupler H11L1 to work as MIDI Input

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator, midi

I received my H11L1 opto isolators (yeah) to use for my MIDI input(s).

However, I cannot receive anything (and tried various circuits).

According to the H11L1 (see [datasheet](http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/3041/MOTOROLA/H11L1/516/2/H11L1.html)) an example circuit is:

[image: Example]
The red box is the part I expect I made a mistake.

According to the MIDI spec an input should look like
[image]

The red part is again the similar part I expect problems with.

The following is a screenshot of my circuit (note I replaced the ferrite beads by cables since I do not have them yet).
[image] The two cables on the right go to pin 4 and 5 of the MIDI cable (I also switched them so that is not the problem).

I use 270 ohm and 220 ohm resistors as advised.

Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong?

Update: It's improved if I put an Hex inverter (74HC14) after Vo (open collector output). The test LED (not in circuit is now shining more whenever MIDI input is received, the Arduino still doesn't get correct data, probably the signal is too much disturbed somehow).

My sketch:

```
#include <MIDI.h>

#define LED 13

MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

void setup() 
{
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);
  MIDI.setHandleNoteOn(MyHandleNoteOn);
  MIDI.setHandleNoteOff(MyHandleNoteOff);
}

void loop() 
{
  MIDI.read();
  delay(1000);
}

void MyHandleNoteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) 
{
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}

void MyHandleNoteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) 
{
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Update:

It seems the opto coupler is probably working correctly, but the Arduino does not pick up the signal correctly. I made a new question on that stack exchange:

[Arduino question about H11L1](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39908/h11l1-opto-isolator-does-not-pass-signal-to-arduino-correctly?noredirect=1#comment81070_39908)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60965/discussion-on-question-by-michel-keijzers-i-cannot-get-opto-coupler-h11l1-to-wor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the opto-isolator from the breadboard. Replace it with an LED. That should blink when you transmit from the MIDI source device.
2. If that's OK then put the opto-isolator back in. Put the LED in series with the pull-up resistor. Repeat the test and you should see the LED blink.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmucvH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure? The black line of the D2 diode is directed towards pin 1, which is also in my circuit. Note that the opto isolator in the official MIDI circuit is the other way around (pin 1 and 2 are switched with respect to the intended circuit)

Comment: You're right. I got confused with the three different orientations in your post. I even drew my schematic with your original post open to check. I'll delete in a few minutes. In the meantime, replace the opto-LED with a visible one just to check that you're feeding data as you think. I'll delete my post in 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending all this time ... and that's a good idea indeed (also I'm building now some simpler circuit around the opto isolator)

Comment: I put a test led after Vo, no difference. However, after adding a hex inverter (74HC14) it's better (but still no correct data).

Comment: See the update. Bedtime in Ireland. Good night.

Comment: Thanks for the update ... the led is changing (from half to full when I press keys etc), however, I still don't get MIDI data in the Arduino... but maybe that's an Arduino problem somehow ... also I did a test and it seems I need to invert the signal (which I hope is not true)... would be strange to add an inverter (I went from 6N137 -> H11L1 to save some space, now I need to add a 16 pin inverter (?) ... Good night to you too (or good morning)... greetings from the Netherlands

Comment: @MichelKeijzers There is no relevant difference between the 6N137 and the H11L1. What test did you do with the inverter (it should *not* be needed)?

Comment: @CL: The test I did was to put a signal directly through the H11L1 anode/cathode, I saw on the output (Vo) that the signal is reversed. But I haven't checked it for a 6N137... I would assume what goes in the opto isolator would come out equally.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers The MIDI output circuit also inverts the signal (it's designed this way so that an idle MIDI line does not use power).

Comment: @CL but I have the feeling the inversion is INSIDE the optocoupler... If I look in another datasheet (https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/H1/H11L1M.pdf ) the truth table on page 2 (bottom) shows H->L and L->H

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Yes; a low voltage on the transmitter results in a current flowing through the MIDI cable, which results in a low voltage at the receiver.

Comment: @CL so all optocouplers invert the signal (because this inverting is probably not only in MIDI cables/transmitting but in mostly all protocols)?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Some digital optocouplers are specially designed to be non-inverting, but most optocouplers indeed are inverting.

Comment: That make sense ... I didn't have time to check a 6N137, but now I read your explanation it would have the same result... I'm glad I do not have to use an inverter (saves a lot of space). And I learnt something (again), thanks.

Comment: @CL: I made a new question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39908/h11l1-opto-isolator-does-not-pass-signal-to-arduino-correctly?noredirect=1#comment81070_39908

Comment: Sorry for the late accepting-answer, my H11L1's work, just forgot to accept the answer. Thanks for helping me out (again).