# Making a simple 1 MIDI IN + 1 arduino MIDI OUT merger (MIDI THRU + TX)

Tags: arduino, midi

From the [Midi DIN spec schematics](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/midi-din-electrical-specification) we can see MIDI THRU is just MIDI OUT directly at the end of a MIDI IN. Is it possible to just add a midi signal from the arduino TX ("FROM UART") to the midi thru (parallel to the MIDI IN) or do I need to get the MIDI IN signal in arduino and mix them digitally before sending to a regular out? Or is there another simple solution to merge the 2?

It is for a keyboard and a pedal (CC64) so notes won't be the same (if it is an issue).

[image]

Comment: You'd at bare minimum need to watch the incoming stream to know when its safe to insert something, and the circuit would be simpler if you ran everything through the ATmega.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it was my first intent but I though maybe it was not necessary to bring these notes in. I guess if a note from the IN is cut in the middle by another note from the TX it would be a problem... I know how to handle that with code, not with electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, combining them in hardware is not possible. Normal way of doing this is to have two MIDI inputs, and two UARTs on a microcontroller receiving messages from both inputs. Then the microprocessor merges the messages so that correct MIDI data bytes belong to correct MIDI status bytes. These merged messages are then sent to one (or several) MIDI outputs.

Comment: This is, of course, the approach one should use, but I disagree that "combining them in hardware is not possible".  I'd almost guarantee that some of the stuff available in the '80s didn't use processors.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Do you have schematics or a link with that kind of build?

Comment: @mikmikmik  looked, but can't find one.  Honestly, it would be faster and easier for you to do it on an Arduino for $30

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to build a MIDI mixer!  You need to work something out so messages go out one at a time, and don't mix together and get garbled.

Comment: Are you talking about me or the mixer? :)

Comment: Yes but is it possible with components?

Comment: It's possible, but you want a microcontroller taking in the messages, and queueing them to be sent out again.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loudly:

1. Thru should not add any delay (beside from a slight "bit-wise" probagation delay from a buffer), so you can daisy chain several devices without adding delay. If MIDI Thru is processed, it's not Thru anymore, but simply MIDI out. This is the difference between the two.
2. If you are using an Atmega, then it uses the same UART register (UDREn) for in and out. So recieve and transmit, at the same time is simply not possible. The only problem would be while transmitting, some incomming messages could mix ind with the data on the Thru/out. I guess a solution could be, using an AND gate as a buffer, so Thru could be switched of while transmitting?

Comment: Your second point is completely wrong. You can use the Atmega UART simultaneously for full duplex reception and transmission just fine. And your suggested solution would corrupt the MIDI stream if you simply use hardware switching between two sources. That is what a MIDI merger does, it takes MIDI messages in and merges them in software in a way that the outgoing messages make sense and they don't interfere with each other.